# Draw ellipse through points

Tags: java, android, math

I am trying to implement some movement of points. This movement should go by ellipse path.
Something like this:

[image: Points go by ellipse path]

I know formula of ellipse:
`(x-x0)^2/a^2+(y-y0)^2/b^2=1` where (x0,y0) - center of ellipse, a - length of semi-major axis, b - length of semi-minor axis.
I used Maple to get y from this:

```
y = (y0*a+sqrt(-x^2*b^2+2*b^2*x*x0-b^2*x0^2+a^2*b^2))/a, 
y = (y0*a-sqrt(-x^2*b^2+2*b^2*x*x0-b^2*x0^2+a^2*b^2))/a
```

For example, I'm using following parameters to get this ellipse:
`x randomly from 100 to 800`, `a=500`, `b=150`, `x0=500`, `y0=500`.
But in any cases my points form simple line, not ellipse.

Code snippet:

```
public static int getYElipse(int a, int b, int x, int x0, int y0){
    return (int) ((y0*a-Math.sqrt(-x^2*b^2+2*b^2*x*x0-b^2*x0^2+a^2*b^2))/a);
}
public static int getYElipse2(int a, int b, int x, int x0, int y0){
    return (int) ((y0*a+Math.sqrt(-x^2*b^2+2*b^2*x*x0-b^2*x0^2+a^2*b^2))/a);
}
...
int x = randomInt(100, 800);
int y = randomBoolean() ? getYElipse(500,150,x,500,500) : getYElipse2(500,150,x,500,500);
```

What am I doing wrong? Any example will be appreciated.

Comment: The `^` operator is XOR, not power. You need to simply do x*x in simple cases such as powers of two or use [Math.pow](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html).

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. You are right! A lot of points form ellipse now, but some of them form line as well. What to do?

Comment: It seems to me these points don't belong to ellipse. That's why they form line. Am I right?

Comment: @Lalaland, you should formalize this as an answer, and I'll apply it.

Comment: Some points formed a line, because I used `Integer` values. When I changed them to `float`, everything became perfect!

Comment: You may achieve better results by using the parametric equation of the ellipse: x = x0 + a.cos(t), y = y0 + b.sin(t)

Comment: I suspect you are running into integer overflows. Change your input 'int' parameters to 'double' and try again.